# How to create issues in Gitlab with Perl

Tags: perl, gitlab, httprequest

I'm using the code below to create issues on Gitlab, but it doesn't work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON;
use Carp;

# establish the API base URI
my $api_base = 'https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/XXXXXXX/issues';

# Try the url with API v4:  https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXXXX/issues but it also didn't work

# personal access token
# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#personal-access-tokens
# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html

my $access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

# $res is an HTTP::Response object
# see: https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response
my $res = $ua->get( $api_base, 
'Private-Token' => $access_token,
'title' => 'Teste',
'description' =>'Description'
) or croak "unable to complete the HTTP request";

my $o = decode_json( $res->decoded_content );

print Dumper $o;
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What output do you get? As far as I know, v3 of the API is deprecated in favour of the v4 API.

Comment: *"... but it doesn't work ..."* as the only error description is not enough. Please explain what you expect what you get as response and why you expect this (i.e. where the API you use is documented) and then show what you get instead (i.e. not matching your expectations).

Comment: I have used https://metacpan.org/pod/GitLab::API::v4 successfully in production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be several issues with this. First of all, `get` does not return false if something is wrong with your setup so check what `$res` actually holds. It might be information about SSL for your HTTPS request.

According to the [API documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#new-issue) it seems like you should do a `POST` to the API v4. You need to create a request with your token as a header and your issue as the body in JSON encoded format.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Carp;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;
use LWP::UserAgent;

# To get the project ID you must query for your projects
# this can be found with a HTTP GET to
# https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/<USERNAME>/projects
my $api_base     = 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT ID>/issues';
my $access_token = 'xxx';

my $ua           = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $request_body = encode_json(
    {
        title       => 'Some tite',
        description => 'See all available parameters in the API doc linked above',
    }
);

my $request = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $api_base );
$request->header( 'Content-Type'  => 'application/json' );
$request->header( 'PRIVATE-TOKEN' => $access_token );
$request->content( $request_body );

my $response         = $ua->request( $request );
my $decoded_response = decode_json( $response->decoded_content );

print Dumper \$decoded_response;
```